# Azure B2C Active Directory: Update one property on all User

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In my current project I'm using Microsofts Azure B2C Actice Directory.

My plan is to update a speciffic property (`testClaim`) of every single user.

What I'm actually doing ist loading all the users in my AD and updating each of them in an `foreach`-loop.

```
        var requestBody = new SetTestClaimRequest
        {
            ClaimName = "testClaim",
            Value = "thisIsATestValue"
        };


        var client = new RestClient("myRes");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
        request.AddJsonBody(requestBody);
```

The problem I'm facing is, that the GraphApi begins to block my requests, after just a few, and just answering with the following error:

```
Error Calling the Graph API: 
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_ThrottledTemporarily",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Your request is throttled temporarily. Please try after 150 seconds."
    },
    "requestId": "ccf8a936-490e-4c4a-87aa-125157b2e6dd",
    "date": "2020-04-17T12:37:44"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this without throttling my request? 
In my opinion throttling isn't a choice cause it would take multiple hours to update the amount of users im dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to bypass throttling limits. It may take some hours to process at the accepted rate. Try 1000 ops per minute maximum. Make sure to implement back off logic if you get a HTTP 429.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know an oppertunity to set the same value to all users with one request or function?

Comment: No, you must patch each user individually.